# How do I leave the Product Storage area?

Tags: stasis

How do I shut down the lockdown so I can leave the Product Storage area?

Presumably, I need to simulate a leak in the Product Storage room, but the game isn't letting me use the Neural Drill on anything in the room.

My current inventory is: High Speed Neural Drill, Full Hypodermic Syringe (filled with blood), Shard of Glass, and Wet Dirty Towel.

I've also already turned the Pressure Valve in the maintenance area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not the product tanks you have to drill.  Instead, you have to drill the fuel storage tanks.  This lifts the lockdown.